# Ruby on Rails - How to get custom output with simple_form grouped_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using simple_form `grouped_select` but I didn't get the output I wanted.

**models**

```
class PartnerName < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :urls, dependent: :destroy
end

#<PartnerName id: 1, name: "technology", app_name: "test">
#<PartnerName id: 2, name: "technology", app_name: "user">
```

---

```
class Url < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :network_partner_name
end

#<Url id: 1, partner_name_id: 1, name: "abc.org">
#<Url id: 2, partner_name_id: 1, name: "qwe.org">
#<Url id: 3, partner_name_id: 2, name: "123.org">
#<Url id: 4, partner_name_id: 2, name: "345.org">
```

---

**view file**

```
= simple_form_for(:query, method: :post) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  .form-row
    .col-auto
      = f.input :network_partner_name_id, collection: PartnerName.order(:name),
                                          include_blank: false
  .form-row
    .col-auto
      = f.input :url_id, collection: PartnerName.order(:name).includes(:urls),
                         as: :grouped_select,
                         group_method: :urls,
                         include_blank: false
```

**Output**

I am getting like the below output with above form.

*For PartnerName*

```
<option value="1">technology</option>
<option value="2">technology</option>
```

*For Url*

```
<optgroup label="technology">
  <option value="1">abc.org</option>
  <option value="2">qwe.org</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="technology">
  <option value="3">123.org</option>
  <option value="4">456.org</option>
</optgroup>
```

**But I want to get output like the below with ParnerName's name and ParnerName's app_name attributes. How can I do this?**

*For PartnerName*

```
<option value="1">technology - test</option>
<option value="2">technology - user</option>
```

*For Url*

```
<optgroup label="technology - test">
  <option value="1">abc.org</option>
  <option value="2">qwe.org</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="technology - user">
  <option value="3">123.org</option>
  <option value="4">456.org</option>
</optgroup>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class method for `PartnerName`

```
class PartnerName < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :urls, dependent: :destroy

  def label_collection
    "#{name} - #{app_name}"
  end
end
```

and use it with the `label_method` and `group_label_method` simple_form helpers:

```
= simple_form_for(:query, method: :post) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  .form-row
    .col-auto
      = f.input : network_partner_name_id, collection: PartnerName.order(:name),
                                           label_method: :label_collection,
                                           include_blank: false
  .form-row
    .col-auto
      = f.input :url_id, collection: PartnerName.order(:name).includes(:urls),
                         as: :grouped_select,
                         group_method: :urls,
                         group_label_method: :label_collection,
                         include_blank: false
```